# Is it possible to programmatically customize a Customizable Salesforce Forecast?

Tags: apex, workflow, opportunity, automation, forecast

I'm working on a project where the client wants the following:

1. Somewhat different from SFDC's native concept of a committed Opportunity, the Opportunity should be set to "Committed" if it exceeds a certain probability, but also a manager can set/unset whether that Opportunity is committed regardless of the stage or probability.
2. While the client allows stages to move forward at any pace, the representative will automatically  losse compensation if the Opportunity stages moves forward too rapidly (if there is a good reason for this, the manager can override this).

We solve both of the above using checkboxes with workflow rules, but this leads us to a problem with the third requirement:

3. The Forcecast should not display those Opportunities which either (1) do not fit the above criteria for commited and (2) will not be compensated.

While we are looking to filter Forecast Reports based on the above, we are wondering if it is possible to actually manipulate the Forecast itself through Apex or any other automated process.

Answer (score 1):

The only forecasts that you can manipulate are the forecast overrides created by users. So that won't help you as the Opportunities will still be shown in the forecasting module. The default forecast is taken straight from the Opportunity records and is not stored separately.

The only options I see are all non-optimal:

1. mapping the Opportunities that you don't want to be included to a separate Opportunity Stage (with forecastcategory 'Omitted' (optionally storing the 'real' stage in a custom field and putting it back when applicable)
2. making sure the quantity and expectedRevenue fields for those Opps get set to 0 (they will still be shown in the Opportunity list but their numbers won't count)
3. creating a separate productFamily for these Opps (they will still be shown but you can ignore that ProductFamily)

Comment: Cheers for the response.  Definitely seems non-optimal.  Will see what else (if anything) we can come up with.

Comment: Let me know any alternative you find, as we have been struggling with very similar issues.